# Which other travel destinations have the same or similar vibe to Bali?

Tags: thailand, vietnam, indonesia, philippines, cambodia

I have a question for those who have experienced Bali (Canggu, Kuta, Seminyak). Are there any other places that exude a comparable vibe? I'm specifically referring to places with vibrant nightlife, elegantly adorned high-end restaurants and cafes, and a substantial presence of young and solo travellers to socialise as a solo traveller.

Comment: You’re specially referring to the Kuta/Seminyak area of Bali then?

Comment: @deceze exactly.

Comment: Rather than towns, you're probably looking for areas/regions...

Comment: Are you looking for a specific price range? If not, Miami and NYC count.

Comment: @JonathanReez yeah, looking for affordable luxary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @lambshaanxy says, Ko Samui matches the bill. This was my first thought. It has just about everything you are listing. While Samui caters mostly to the budget and mid-range crowd, there are high-end hotels and restaurants. Plus Ko Pha Ngan and other beach party islands.

Boracay could also be a match. Again an island with lots of beaches, a younger crowd, and night life.

Answer (score 12):

There's nothing quite like Bali, but some ideas:

- Gili Trawangan, off Lombok; only a few hours by boat from Bali
- Ko Samui, Thailand: nightlife in Chaweng, hip boutique hotels in Bophut and Choeng Mon, etc
- Phuket, I'm not up to speed on where's hip these days but like Bali it's large enough to cater to most and Patong certainly ticks the nightlife box
- Okinawa, Japan, where the Japanese surfer crowd hangs out

Bangkok doesn't have much in the way of beaches, but in terms of nightlife and high-end restaurants etc it's hard to beat.  Honorary mention to the beach clubs of Sentosa, Singapore, although they're too pricey for the backpacker set.

Comment: I live in Okinawa. The only “vibrant nightlife” spots that I’m aware of are the nasty bars frequented by US military. There are some good restaurants, but the emphasis is on the food, and very few are “elegantly adorned”. Most of the travelers are families from China, Taiwan, Korea, or the Japanese mainland. The Japanese surfer crowd hangs out in Chiba, and surfer culture does not seem to be what the OP is seeking, anyway.